# What is the difference between systemd's 'oneshot' and 'simple' service types?

Tags: systemd

What is the difference between `systemd` service `Type` `oneshot` and `simple`? 
This [link](https://jason.the-graham.com/2013/03/06/how-to-use-systemd-timers/) states to use `simple` instead of `oneshot` for timers.  I am not able to understand it correctly.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The `Type=oneshot` service unit:

- blocks on a start operation until the first process exits, and its state will be reported as "activating";
- once the first process exits, transitions from "activating" straight to "inactive", unless `RemainAfterExit=true` is set (in which case it becomes "active" with no processes!);
- may have any number (0 or more) of `ExecStart=` directives which will be executed sequentially (waiting for each started process to exit before starting the next one);
- may leave out `ExecStart=` but have `ExecStop=` (useful together with `RemainAfterExit=true` for arranging things to run on system shutdown).

The `Type=simple` service unit:

- does not block on a start operation (i. e. becomes "active" immediately after forking off the first process, even if it is still initializing!);
- once the first process exits, transitions from "active" to "inactive" (there is no `RemainAfterExit=` option);
- is generally discouraged because there is no way to distinguish situations like "exited on start because of a configuration error" from "crashed after 500ms of runtime" and suchlike.

Both `Type=oneshot` and `Type=simple` units:

- ignore any children of the first process, so do not use these modes with forking processes (note: you may use `Type=oneshot` with `KillMode=none`, **but only do this if you know what you are doing**).

Comment: intelfx says that the `Type=oneshot` service unit "can have no `ExecStart=`". This is not true. In fact, services of type `oneshot` can have multiple `ExecStart=` directives. See any recent man page for `systemd.service` for more information.

Comment: @rlandster: Why is this "not true"? [systemd.service(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) says under `ExecStart=`: "Unless Type= is oneshot, exactly one command must be given. When Type=oneshot is used, zero or more commands may be specified."

Comment: agree that "can have no" is confusing. that is not true. but i think you can't have `ExecReload`

Comment: By "can have no" I assume that @intelfx meant "can have zero or more," or "does not require a," and not "can't have any." However, rewording it for clarity would help future readers.

Comment: "Can even have no" would be better wording perhaps

Answer (score 1):

From systemd's point of view, `Type=simple` is kind of fire and forget. Systemd just forks a process defined in `ExecStart=` and goes on its way, even if the process fails to start.

Comment: `Type=simple` processes are still monitored by systemd, and will be restarted depending on the value of the `Restart` setting.